# Python creating dictionary from list and tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When I iterate over a dictionary like so:

```
dict2={
'Joe':('Caucasian','Male', 35, 7.5),
'Kevin':('Black','Male', 55, 9.5),
 More tuples here like the one above
}
```

The data is bigger but it doesn't matter here.

What I am trying to accomplish **is to create a new dictionary with the information from the tuples**. Like so:

```
dict_i_want = {
  "Name": Joe, 
  "Ethiniticy": "Caucasian", 
  "Gender":"Male",
  "Voter_age": 35, 
  "Score": 7.5
}
```

Here is my code:

```
dict_i_want = {}
for k,v in dict2.items():
    dict_i_want["Name"] = k
    dict_i_want['Ethiniticy'] = v[0]
    dict_i_want['Gender'] = v[1]
    dict_i_want['Voter_age'] = v[2]
    dict_i_want['Score'] = v[3]
```

But when I do

```
print(dict_i_want)
{'Name': 'Kevin', 'Ethiniticy': 'Black', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Voter_age': 55, 'Score': 9.5}
```

The result is just the last tuple that I have in mydict2. No all the tuples.
What I am doing wrong if I have the loop?

**PS: I don't want to use any modules or import anything here. No built-in function like zip() or something like that. I want to hard code the solution**

Comment: What output do you expect for, say, _two_ or more such tuples? `dict_i_want` is only for _one_ tuple, right?

Comment: I edit the question to be more clear. It only returns the last tuple in the dictionary. "dict_i_want" has only one line with the data from the last tuple.

Comment: I understand what it returns, but what do you _want_ it to return? Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, and operations like `dict_i_want["Name"] = k` overwrite the previous value of `dict_i_want["Name"]`

Comment: I see. What I want is to build the dictionary with all the data from the tuple. I cant see to find a way to do that, but I get the mistake.

Comment: Yeah, it's not possible to create a _single_ dictionary with all elements like that, but you can create a list of such dictionaries - one dictionary per tuple.

Comment: I understand that.

Answer (score 3):

@ForceBru answered your question - your best bet is a list of dictionaries unless you want to create a dictionary of dictionaries with unique keys for each sub-dictionary.  Going with the list approach you could do something like this:

Example:

```
from pprint import pprint

dict2 = {
    'Joe': ('Caucasian', 'Male', 35, 7.5),
    'Kevin': ('Black', 'Male', 55, 9.5),
}

dicts_i_want = [
    {"name": name, "ethnicity": ethnicity, "gender": gender, "voter_age": voter_age, "score": score}
    for name, (ethnicity, gender, voter_age, score) in dict2.items()
]
pprint(dicts_i_want)
```

Output:

```
[{'ethnicity': 'Caucasian',
  'gender': 'Male',
  'name': 'Joe',
  'score': 7.5,
  'voter_age': 35},
 {'ethnicity': 'Black',
  'gender': 'Male',
  'name': 'Kevin',
  'score': 9.5,
  'voter_age': 55}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dict keys has to be unique. You're just overwriting your dict each cycle in your loop. It's just how dicts work.